# How to get response parameters in Django?

Tags: python, django, oauth

I want to implement login with twitter without using any library for my django app. I am sending the user to login page using a request function in views by passing the tokens which is successfully going to the twitter login page.
Twitter redirects user to a url which I have configured as

`login/twitter/callback`

How do I access the parameters sent by twitter on this url using a view ?

Comment: request.GET or request.POST?

Comment: it is Oauth GET request

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your case requires to extract parameters from a request. Twitter redirects the user to your application, and the redirect makes a request to your server

You can get using the following approach:

assuming your URL is called as GET `login/twitter/callback?token=abc123`

```
def twitter_callback(request):
  token = request.GET.get('token')
  if token is None:
    # do something if parameter is missing

  # do other things
```

If your view expects other methods, you can get them as well:

POST `myurl/path?param=abc123`

```
def post_view(request):
  param = request.POST.get('param')
```